# Using YADCF with JQuery UI with "changeMonth: true, changeYear: true"

Tags: jquery-ui, datatable, yadcf

a bit of assistance please.

Using YADCF with JQuery UI, and trying to include the functions: changeMonth: true,  changeYear: true

In the example for JQueryUI this is what they use:

```
$( "#yourID" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
```

With YADCF I am not sure how to add it. This is what my code looks like now:

```
.yadcf([
                    {column_number: 0, filter_type: "range_date", 
                    datepicker_type: 'jquery-ui', 
                    changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
     filter_container_id: "external_filter_container"}
```

I have also tried inserting "changeMonth: true, changeYear: true," into

```
var datepickerDefaults = {
```

and separately targeting the YADCF id with

```
 $( "#YADCFID" ).datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
```

So far no luck, any suggestions?

UPDATE: Although the form works the sorting does not.

Current Script:

```
    var oTable;     
        $(document).ready(function () {
            'use strict';           
            $('#example').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }],
            "order": [],
              dom: '<"pos1"B><"pos2"li><"pos3"f>tp',
              buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
          }).yadcf([
                {column_number: 0, filter_type: "range_date",             
 filter_container_id: "external_filter_container",
    filter_plugin_options: {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }
    }
            ]);
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
```

and the html:

```
  <tr>
      <td>21/06/2017</td>     
  </tr>
<tr class="t-two">
    <td>21/06/2017</td> 
</tr>
```

The search result returns wrong months i.e. 02/02/2017 when I select range 01/06/2017 - 02/06/2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [filter_plugin_options](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L222) attribute for that

Like this:

```
.yadcf([
    {
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "range_date", 
        //datepicker_type: 'jquery-ui', this one is redundant because its the default value anyway
        filter_container_id: "external_filter_container",
        filter_plugin_options: {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you, 2 quick questions.

1. I feel horrible bugging you about this minor stuff. I looked for documentation, but could not find this particular issue. Did I miss it somewhere?

2. After installing it the code works but the sorting does not.

Comment: what issue are you talking about as for sorting does not work - please provide a test page - jsbin / jsfiddle

Comment: ok I'll have to set it up. It's saying it's too large. Will take me  a minute. I posted the code in the OP, in case you see if off the batt

Comment: http://www.talaadthai.co.th/test_234/tes <-- let me know if you can use this.

Select 01/06/2017 - 03/06/2017 (1st and 3rd of this month)

The results will include:
03/05/2017
03/05/2017
01/06/2017
03/03/2017
03/02/2017
03/02/2017
03/02/2017
02/02/2017
02/02/2017

Comment: @user1701964 , try setting dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" outside of the filter_plugin_options because its not plugin specific attribute but rather yadcf filter... also try `dd/mm/yyyy`